# how to fetch two column from a file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, amazon-ec2

```
 for snapshot in $(cat "$EC2_HOME/SnapshotsDOW_$today_date" | awk '{print $2}')
 do
    ec2-delete-snapshot $snapshot
 done
```

this code fetches one column now i have to fetch two colums, how can i do that and store there  value in a variable:

```
:: Create snapshots of all attached volumes
for /F "tokens=2,3" %%d IN (' type "%EC2_HOME%\Working\ActiveVolumes_%date-today%.txt" ') do for /F "tokens=3,5*" %%a IN (' type "%EC2_HOME%\Working\InstanceNames_%date-today%.txt" ') do if %%a EQU %%e call ec2-create-snapshot "%%d" -d "%date-today%: Daily Backup for %%b (VolID:%%d InstID:%%e)"
```

this is a batch code which I want to convert into shell script

i have tried this :

```
#Create snapshots of all attached volumes
for volumeid,instanceid in $(cat "$EC2_HOME/ActiveVolumes_$today_date" | awk '{print $2,$3}') 
  do 
   for instance_id,name in $(cat "$EC2_HOME/Instances_$today_date" | awk"{print $3,$5}')
     do
     if ["$instanceid" -eq "$instance_id" ]
     then
        do ec2-create-snapshot "$volumeid" -d "$today_date: Daily Backup for $instance_id (VolID:$volumeid InstID:$instance_id)"
        done
        fi
    done
  done
```

where contents of volume.txt are

`ATTACHMENT  vol-fa0         i-26011     /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-20T06:42:49+0000   true
ATTACHMENT   vol-36b         i-e3d6  /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000   true`

and instances.txt are

`TAG    instance    i-42370     Name    Linux_Test`

Comment: This fetches first and second columns. `awk '{ printf "%s %s\n", $1, $2 }'`.

Comment: is this code correct :`
#Create snapshots of all attached volumes
for volumeid,instanceid in $(cat "$EC2_HOME/SnapshotsDOW_$today_date" | awk '{print $2,$3}') 
  do 
   for instance_id,name in $(cat "$EC2_HOME/Instances_$today_date" | awk"{print $3,$5}')
     do
  if ["$instanceid" -eq "$instance_id" ]
  then
  do ec2-create-snapshot "$volumeid" -d "$today_date: Daily Backup for $instance_id (VolID:$volumeid InstID:$instance_id)"
  done
        fi
    done
  done`

Comment: Put your code in edits to original question.

Comment: The code will not work as for-loops in bourne shell will not take multiple variables. One option is to output things concatenated, then split them within the loop: `for baz in $(echo "foo:bar") ; do a="$(echo $baz|cut -d: -f1)" ; b="$(echo $baz|cut -d: -f2)" ; done`

Comment: It seems `volume.txt` and `instances.txt` are probably multiple lines, but you did not format your text correctly. Can you please adjust your post to use block style formatting for those? In the toolbar the `{}` button converts the selected text to block style code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking for this:

```
awk '{print $2, $3}' "$EC2_HOME/ActiveVolumes_$today_date" | while read vol_id inst_id; do
    awk '{print $3, $5}' "$EC2_HOME/Instances_$today_date" | while read inst_id2 name; do
        if test "$inst_id" = "$inst_id2"; then
            ec2-create-snapshot "$vol_id" -d "$today_date: Daily Backup for $inst_id (VolID:$vol_id InstID:$inst_id)"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: but there are no of conditions which i have to check ? please if u could help me in converting the code i would be very thankful to you. please see the code in the question

Comment: If you include some sample input and output, then maybe I can do it easily, we'll see.

Comment: I don't see what are the lines in the sample files you gave. Please adjust the formatting of the question to use block-style. Please also explain what commands should be executed based on those sample files, and what is the logic to check for.

Comment: @junos: i have tried to format it. i will xplain what i have to do . i  want to fetch the volume id and instance id  ( column 2, 3) from volume.txt file. i also want to fetch the instance id, name from instance file( column 3,5). then i want to check if the instance id fetched are equal from both the files , if yes create snapshot of volume with description that the volume `%volume_id` for `instance_id`

Comment: hey will u help me in doing that ?

Comment: let me try, i will let u know.

Comment: please help rectifying this error. i am not able to solve this

Comment: I made a minor change that might help a bit. But from your error message it looks like the `ec2-delete-snapshot` command doesn't have a `-d` flag. If you run `ec2-delete-snapshot -h`, does it tell you it has a `-d` flag?

Comment: its actually create snapshot not delete

Comment: no not working ps `ec2-create-snapshot  vol-f66409a0 -d 2013-12-10: Daily Backup for i-26048111 (VolID:vol-f6640 InstID:i-261)
WARNING:  Ignoring extra parameter(s): [ vol-f66a0 ]
Client.MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter volume
`

Comment: hey its working, i have edited the code. thanks. will ping you once done with entire script

Comment: I noticed a mistake, I removed `"$snapshot"` from the final command line, it should work now.

Comment: hey can you tell me how to do : `:: Create a file with all latest snapshots
FOR /F "tokens=5" %%a in (' ec2-describe-snapshots ^|find "SNAPSHOT" ^|sort /+64') do set "var=%%a" 
set "latestdate=%var:~0,10%" 
call ec2-describe-snapshots |find "SNAPSHOT"|sort /+64 |find "%latestdate%">"%EC2_HOME%\Working\SnapshotsLatest_%date-today%.txt"`

Comment: i want to find the file that contains the latest snapshots? how to do that

Comment: That's really a different question... Anyway, I'll be off now, so good luck! (It looks to me you have to learn a bit more of shell scripting if you want to migrate DOS to bash and maintain.)

Comment: i have posted annothe question , please have a look if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489501/error-in-shell-scripting