# Bug in shell scriptin

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-ec2

Hi i am trying a code in shell script. i am trying to convert the code from batch script to shell script but getting an error.

CODE IN SHELL SCRIPT

`latestdate=$(ec2-describe-snapshots | grep ^SNAPSHOT | sort -k 5 | awk '{print $5}')
ec2-describe-snapshots | grep SNAPSHOT.*$latestdate | > "$EC2_HOME/SnapshotsLatest_$today_date"`

but getting the error :

`grep: 2013-12-10T09:55:34+0000: No such file or directory 
grep: 2013-12-11T04:16:49+0000: No such file or directory 
grep: 2013-12-11T04:17:57+0000: No such file or directory`

SAMPLE OUTPUT OF ece-describe-snapshots:

`SNAPSHOT snap-5e20 vol-f660 completed 2013-12-10T08:00:30+0000 100% 109030037527 10 2013-12-10: Daily Backup for i-2111 (VolID:vol-f9a0 InstID:i-2601)`

please not that if there are snapshots created on `2013-12-10, 2013-12-11, 2013-12-12`. It means that the latest_date should be `2013-12-12` and all the snaphshot created on `2013-12-12` should be saved in file.

I want to sort the snapshots according to dates and want to save the snapshots that are made in latest date in a file.

Any suggestion or lead is appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: You should delete this question, as this was already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489501/error-in-shell-scripting/20507633?noredirect=1#comment30662940_20507633

Comment: Please avoid re-posting questions. Secondary answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510801/how-to-fix-the-error-in-the-bash-shell-script .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with Bash, but try this

```
latestdate=`ec2-describe-snapshots | grep ^SNAPSHOT | sort -k 5 | awk '{print $5}'`;
ec2-describe-snapshots | grep SNAPSHOT.*${latestdate} > ${EC2_HOME}"/SnapshotsLatest_"${today_date}
```